# arreglos con un mismo indice

Tags: php, codeigniter

estoy trabajando con arrays los cuyales tiene como indice el codigo de la persona, esta persona ejemplo:

```
[PER0076] => Array
    (
        [fecha_registro] => 2018-03-27 09:52:31.642576
        [codigo_persona] => PER0076
        [cedula_ubicacion] => 0814030010000001
        [codigo_estado] => 08
        [nombre_estado] => CARABOBO
        [codigo_municipio] => 14
        [nombre_municipio] => VALENCIA
        [codigo_parroquia] => 03
        [nombre_parroquia] => URBANA MIGUEL PEÃ‘A
        [codigo_sector] => 001
        [nombre_sector] => BRISAS DEL ARENAL
        [fecha_abordaje] => 2018-03-02
        [codigo_origen] => 1
        [origen] => Plan Vulnerabilidad
        [nombres_apellidos] => RAMON FERNANDEZ
        [cedula] => 2837999
        [fecha_nacimiento] => 1942-05-22
        [edad] => 75
        [meses] => 9
        [dias] => 8
        [genero] => 1
        [embarazo] => 2
        [cbi] => 220
        [peso] => 52.7
        [talla] => 1.62
        [descripcion_situacion] => 1
)
```

y este otro

```
[PER0076] => Array
    (
        [fecha_registro] => 2018-03-27 09:52:31.642576
        [codigo_persona] => PER0076
        [cedula_ubicacion] => 0814030010000001
        [codigo_estado] => 08
        [nombre_estado] => CARABOBO
        [codigo_municipio] => 14
        [nombre_municipio] => VALENCIA
        [codigo_parroquia] => 03
        [nombre_parroquia] => URBANA MIGUEL PEÃ‘A
        [codigo_sector] => 001
        [nombre_sector] => BRISAS DEL ARENAL
        [fecha_abordaje] => 2018-03-02
        [codigo_origen] => 1
        [origen] => Plan Vulnerabilidad
        [nombres_apellidos] => RAMON FERNANDEZ
        [cedula] => 2837999
        [fecha_nacimiento] => 1942-05-22
        [edad] => 75
        [meses] => 9
        [dias] => 8
        [genero] => 1
        [embarazo] => 2
        [cbi] => 230
        [peso] => 58.2
        [talla] => 1.62
        [descripcion_situacion] => 1
    )
```

lo que me gustaria saber es como hacer para meter estos dos arrays en uno solo donde el indice sea el codigo de la persona, o como podria verificar si el codigo de la persona ya existe desde el segundo solo tomar los valores desde el CBI al ultimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que tienes un `array` de `arrays` por lo tanto, puede hacer uso de `in_array` para verificar si ya existe un `arreglo` dentro del `arreglo principal`, como estas manejando todo por `indices` no hace falta utilizar las `keys`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
//Arreglo principal
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
//Nuevo arreglo a entrar
$nuevo = array("Volvo",22,18);
//Verificas si el arreglo nuevo ya existe en el principal
if (!in_array($nuevo, $cars)) {
  //Si no existe lo agregas al arreglo
    $cars[] = $nuevo;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una función de PHP llamada `array_key_exists`, que lo que hace es decir: si existe la llave entonces no me haga nada, si no entonces lléneme el array. Ejemplo:

```
//Si no existe esa llave en el array

if(!array_key_exists("PER0076",$array)){
 $array["PER0076"] = $llenarArray;
}
```